# Index for max(column2)

Tags: mysql

For a table with two non-null columns: `id (primary)`, and `date (indexed)`, I get the following entry in the mysql-slow log.

```
# Query_time: 16.316747  Lock_time: 0.000049 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 616021
SET timestamp=1451837371;
select max(date) from mytable where id<896173;
```

I ran `EXPLAIN` on this query, and this is the outcome.

```
id            = 1
select_type   = SIMPLE
table         = mytable
type          = range
possible_keys = PRIMARY
key           = PRIMARY
key_len       = 4
ref           = NULL
rows          = 337499
Extra         = Using where
```

I tried to edit the `date` index to add the `id` column to it. However, it is still the case that the number of rows examined is high. What can I do to reduce this number?

Comment: You have index   by date, id or by id, date. and how much row are with id <896173?

Comment: I have index by date, id. There are 616021 rows with id < 896173.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine needs to look at all rows where `id<896173` and select the `max(date)` from that. Having an index on date and an index on id does not really help. Either MySQL can use the index on date to identify only a subset of rows.

However, that subset is big enough that it will be faster to read all the rows (with sequential access) than it would be to read only a subset (with random access).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using an index more selective like the inverse of your

```
use an index based on  id, date
```

in this way the id drive the selection and the date fiels support the selection.